# Execv function in C not reading a variable that is passed in as an argument

Tags: c, file-io, io, exec, execv

So I am building my own shell and one of the commands I want is the "cat" function. To do this, I am using the execv function and passing in the correct bin path of "cat" as well as the file name that I want to concatenate and print to the terminal.

The code below works perfectly fine, but I am hard coding in the file name that I want to "cat"

```
void cat(char *fileName)
{
    char *bin_path = "/bin/cat";
    printf("%d\n", strncmp(fileName, "junk.txt", strlen("junk.txt"))); // returns 0, meaning equal values
    char *args[] = {bin_path, "junk.txt", NULL};
    execv(bin_path, args);
}
```

The output from above is shown below
[argument is hardcoded in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAkGQ.png)

But I want to be able to make this function dynamic and have the file name be passed into the function, so that's why I have the variable fileName as a parameter. You can see that I am comparing the string literal "junk.txt" with fileName variable and it returns 0, meaning they are EQUAL! But when I pass in the variable fileName to the execv function, it doesn't work. Please see my broken code below

```
void cat(char *fileName)
{
    char *bin_path = "/bin/cat";
    printf("%d\n", strncmp(fileName, "junk.txt", strlen("junk.txt"))); // returns 0, meaning equal values
    char *args[] = {bin_path, fileName, NULL};
    execv(bin_path, args);
}
```

[no file or directory that matches that name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIJmn.png)

Anyone have any idea why that is?

Comment: Use `strcmp` instead of `strncmp`. I think you will find they are not equal. I'm guessing there is a trailing `\n` in the `fileName` variable. If that doesn't help then please provide complete code as a [mre]. We need to see exactly how the functions are called and what is passed to it.

Comment: Try absolute paths.

Comment: why do people think strncomp is like a "safer" strcmp? :D

Answer (score 2):

Likely you read the file name as a whole line and got the new-line character at the end of the line. `strncmp` only compares up to the number of characters you tell it, so the zero result does not prove the strings are equal. We can even see the new-line in the error message from `cat`: After “junk.txt”, its “:” is on a new line.

Change the calling routine to remove the unwanted new-line character from the name.

In the future, always provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with debugging questions. The error in this case was in code you did not show, in the calling routine, and that is why a MRE should always be provided.